# Limit POST Hook to git branch, not repository, on Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Complicated title, let me explain.

I want to limit an automatic POST hook when I push to the `master` branch; so it won't fire when I push to the `dev` branch. This is so the app will only deploy to the live servers when the changes have been merged with `master` and the new `master` passes the unit tests.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't limit when BitBucket fires its POST hook; but you can use the [contents of the POST](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management#POSThookmanagement-POSTData) to make the decision about whether or not to proceed with the deployment. Just parse the JSON that BitBucket sends you and only continue if any of the `"commits"` elements have a `"branch"` of "master", for example.

Comment: Thanks, you made me look a little deeper. I'm an idiot, and completely missed a setting in codeship.io ~ they have branch specific deployment, and I just need to set it to master instead of all.

Comment: Somehow merge commits omit the master branch information in the POST payload. Any idea for a safe-proofed way to check whether these merge commits include a master branch?